# Showing image with 2 channels

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using goodFeaturesToTrack() method to locate corners from an image. However when I try to view the image, using imshow(), I get an error:

OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage

Here is the code:

```
Mat outPutImage;
goodFeaturesToTrack(src_gray, outPutImage, 20, 0.5, 500);
imshow("Output", outPutImage);
```

goodFeaturesToTrack takes in only a 1 channel image and outputs a 2 channel image. How can I convert the 2 channel to 3 channel or is there an alternative for imshow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208254/showing-image-with-2-channels/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For questions about OpenCV, please use [answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0